# Google Cloud Postgres Server Connection Issue

Tags: postgresql, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-datastore, google-cloud-sql, wildfly-10

I am getting `"Could not obtain connection to query metadata : Cannot create Poolable ConnectionFactory (Connection refused. Check that the hostname and port are correct and that the postmaster is accepting TCP/IP connections.)"`
When I am trying to connect to Postgress through my code,

I tried connecting through ssh through this command its getting connected

```
gcloud beta sql connect instance_name --user=USER
```

but when I am trying to connect through normal PSQL Command its giving connection TimeOut.
Google Cloud SQL Connection Stopped all of a sudden , while it was running for more than 5 days.

I am trying to connect as

```
<beans:bean id="dataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource"
    destroy-method="close">
    <beans:property name="driverClassName" value="org.postgresql.Driver" />
    <beans:property name="url"
        value="jdbc:postgresql://databaseip:5432/db" />
    <beans:property name="username" value="user" />
    <beans:property name="password" value="password" />
</beans:bean>
```

Please help me to get it connected properly ,let us know what is the issue
I am using PostgreSQL 9.6 
and Google Cloud
wildfly-10.1.0.Final server which is hosted in internal ip of the google cloud server

Answer (score 0):

Cloud SQL instances have a maximum number of connections that depends on the instance tier [limit](https://cloud.google.com/sql/pricing#machine-types-pricing). If your setup was working before and suddenly stopped, it is possible you are reaching this limit. You may use "Connection pooling" method as described [here](https://cloud.google.com/sql/faq#connections) to manage a large number of connections in your SQL instance.

Also as described in the public [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/postgres/connect-external-app#appaccessIP) make sure that you have authorized the IP address of the external application through which you are trying to access the SQL instance and you are not using private network IP.